# How to get rid of whitespace in element of dictionary?

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary, removing-whitespace

I am trying to extract only the string without whitespace of an element in a dictionary. This is how my element looks currently:

```
u'GYM-7874 '
```

I only want to extract the value without the whitespace so "GYM-7874" only so that I can compare it with another list of strings. I tried using the .strip() method to get rid of whitespaces but unfortunately that only works with string. How do I get rid of the white space and only extract the characters?

```
# json_ob is the string array of dictionary 
title = json_ob[index]["title"]
title.strip()
```

Comment: You are using title.strip(), but it is attempting to strip the entire array rather than just the string title within the array. Try `json_ob[index]["title"].strip()`

Comment: Where is the problem?  `strip` works on strings, and that is what you have.  What did you get, compared to what you expect?  Follow the posting guidelines and show the actual input and output from your operation.

Comment: @BlakeOttinger `title` isn't the array, it's the value of `json_ob[index]["title"]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`strip()` doesn't modify the string in place (strings are immutable in Python). You need to assign the result back to the variable.

```
title = title.strip()
```